# Can I delete and recreate an AWS root account with the same e-mail address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

A [CloudFormation template](https://github.com/awslabs/amediamanager/blob/master/cfn/classic/amm-master.cfn.json) (written by Amazon's own experts, ironically) failed to create its stacks and then failed to delete the resources it had created. Deleting the IAM user account where these failed stack creations occurred will not clean up resources, so I'm faced with closing the root account.

If I delete the root account can I recreate it again, and how long will I have to wait to create another root account with the same e-mail?

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any need to delete the root account.  Even if you can't delete the resources via CloudFormation, you should be able to delete them manually in the web console or using the CLI, and then when you try to delete the CF stack again it will notice that the resources are gone and continue.  There are *very* few resources which can be put into a state where they can't be deleted by manual commands and waiting a short time.

If you can't delete resources manually (even as root) then something has gone very wrong with your account and you should contact AWS tech support.

---

To answer the actual question posed, though, AWS accounts are not uniquely keyed by email address; you can actually change the primary email, so you should maybe try creating a new account and swapping the email addresses over, before deleting the old one.

Comment: It's such a hairball that manual deletion won't work.  Everything has dependencies on something else.  It sounds like I can only have one account per e-mail address.